# JQuery .hide() not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having an issue getting proper show/hide behavior in Firefox. Site works in Chrome/Safari. Not worrying about IE for now.

Site is here:

http://chrismcaleenan.com/map/?page_id=6

You can see the desired behavior when user mouseover/mouseout/clicks a state on the map in Chrome/Safari (ignore inset - this is still a work in progress). In Firefox the site seems to handle mouseover but not mouseout nor click.

Here's what I think is the relevant code, though error could be in actual CSS or elsewhere:

```
//actions on poly mouseover     
        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addListener(eval(statesPoly[i]), 'mouseover', function() {
                    this.setOptions({ strokeWeight: '2' });
                    $("#"+statesPoly[i]).addClass("highlight");
                    if(map.getZoom() <= 6) 
                    $('#supp_data'+i).show();
                });
            })(i);
        }

        //actions on poly click     
        var zoomArray = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            zoomArray[i]=0;

            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addListener(eval(statesPoly[i]), 'click', function() {
                    if (!zoomArray[i]) {                
                        map.panTo(eval(stateCenters[i]));
                        map.setZoom(7);
                        polyArray[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '0' });
                        zoomArray[i] = 1;   
                        $('#supp_data'+i).hide();
                        $('#inset-map').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        map.panTo(myLatLng);
                        map.setZoom(6);
                        $('#inset-map').show();

                        //for some reason bug causes 11,12 to skip - adding manual reset
                        polyArray[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[i] = 0;
                        polyArray[11].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[11] = 0;
                        polyArray[12].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[12] = 0;

                        for (n = 0; n < polyArray.length; n++) {
                            polyArray[n].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                            zoomArray[n] = 0;   
                        }

                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }

        //actions on table mouseover 
        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(statesPoly[i]), 'mouseover', function() {
                    $("#"+statesPoly[i]).addClass("highlight");
                    polyArray[i].setOptions({ strokeWeight: '2' });
                    if(map.getZoom() <= 6)
                    $('#supp_data'+i).show();
                });
            })(i);
        }

        //actions on table click    
        var zoomArray = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            zoomArray[i]=0;

            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(statesPoly[i]), 'click', function() {
                    if (!zoomArray[i]) {                
                        map.panTo(eval(stateCenters[i]));
                        map.setZoom(7);
                        polyArray[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '0' });
                        zoomArray[i] = 1;   
                        $('#supp_data'+i).hide();
                        $('#inset-map').hide();

                    }
                    else {
                        map.panTo(myLatLng);
                        map.setZoom(6);
                        $('#inset-map').show();


                        //for some reason bug causes 11,12 to skip - adding manual reset
                        polyArray[i].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[i] = 0;
                        polyArray[11].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[11] = 0;
                        polyArray[12].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                        zoomArray[12] = 0;

                        for (n = 0; n < polyArray.length; n++) {
                            polyArray[n].setOptions({ fillOpacity: '.8' });
                            zoomArray[n] = 0;   
                        }

                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }

        //actions on poly mouseout 
        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addListener(eval(statesPoly[i]), 'mouseout', function() {
                    this.setOptions({ strokeWeight: '1' });
                    $("#"+statesPoly[i]).removeClass("highlight");
                    $('#supp_data'+i).hide();
                });
            })(i);
        }

        //actions on table mouseout
        for (var i = 0; i < statesPoly.length; i++) {
            (function(i){
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(statesPoly[i]), 'mouseout', function() {
                    $("#"+statesPoly[i]).removeClass("highlight");
                    polyArray[i].setOptions({ strokeWeight: '1' });
                    $('#supp_data'+i).hide();
                });
            })(i);
        }
```

Comment: What does it say when you try debugging it in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I never put one of my Poly objects in the array. Chrome and Safari kept running the script, but Firefox killed it (w/out error).

Comment: You should Accept your Answer so this SO Question is resolved.